# VB.NET For Each through a DataLayer

Tags: vb.net

I'm helping someone fix a VB application but struggling with a little bit of syntax.

I have the following:

```
Dim _dt = Datalayer.ConvertSqlDataSourceToDataTable(SqlDataSourceCart)
If _dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    'For Each here...
End If
```

What I need to do is loop through every row using a For or For Each loop and get the ProductID field.  I think it should be along the lines of:

```
Dim someString As String   
For Each _row As DataRow In _dt.DataSet.Tables(0).Rows
    someString += _row(ProductID) & ", "
Next
```

Comment: I changed it to simply _dt.Rows and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming _dt is alrady of type `DataTable`:

```
Dim someStringBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
For Each _row As DataRow In _dt.Rows
    someStringBuilder.Append(_row.Field(Of String)("ProductID")).Append(",")
Next
If someStringBuilder.Length<>0 Then someStringBuilder.Length -= 1
Dim someString = someStringBuilder.ToString()
```

or, if you can use [LINQ-To-DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb386977.aspx):

```
Dim IDs = _dt.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("ProductID"))
someString  = String.Join(",", IDs)
```

Comment: Yes, it is the _dt.Rows that fixed it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
someString += _row["ProductID"] & ", "
```